# The getGeneratedKeys() to print key don't work. Why?

Tags: java, sql

Why the getGeneratedKeys() return NULL? this is my code:

```
public void insertNewPreventivo(String cliente, int idProdottoNew, int[] opzioniNew) {
    String query = "INSERT INTO preventivo (prodotto,cliente) VALUES (?,?)";
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(query, ps.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        ps.setInt(1, idProdottoNew);
        ps.setString(2, cliente);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
        if (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And this is my DB:

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra             |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| id        | datetime    | NO   | PRI | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
| prodotto  | int         | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                   |
| cliente   | varchar(45) | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                   |
| impiegato | varchar(45) | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                   |
| prezzo    | double      | NO   |     | 0                 |                   |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

I want print "id" value. Thanks

Comment: Is the database MySQL?  I was able to get generated keys back with your code by switching the 'id' column from 'datetime' to an AUTO_INCREMENT 'int'.  I'm not completely sure, but it seems that the 'mysql-connector' JDBC driver is assuming that generated keys will be integers.  If you control the schema you could get around this by using the int 'id' key, and having another datetime column with default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `executeUpdate` method never returns the generated keys. Here you just get the row count.

Try with `execute()` instead and get the ResultSet with getGeneratedKeys()

Also "some drivers" requires to give `generated` column name instead of constant(return_generated_keys)

like this `PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql, new String[]{"id"})`